# android:supportsRtl doesn't really work

Tags: android, android-layout

i made this android:supportsRtl="false" for my application
and yet it still flip my layout views when i change the language from English to Arabic and verse versa  any clues what to do to prevent the views from flipping not matter what language it runs on or API level
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If targetSdkVersion is set to 16 or lower then it will ignore the RTL support. Otherwise if you change the language then it will support RTL.

As this attribute is supported from the API 17.
Ref Link: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element